# tensorflow Variable Initialization error : Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable

Tags: variables, tensorflow, initialization, deep-learning

Why is this happening?
[Error message - Attempting to uninitialized Variable Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rcrd.jpg)
here is my source:
[source - Learning .JPG Image in computer using tensorflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxh4c.jpg)

I don't know why this error occur...
I already used two types of variable initialization function:

1. `tf.global_variables_initializer()`
2. `tf.local_variables_initializer()`

Comment: Don't post code as an image!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `tf.global_variables_initializer()` and invoke it after you defined all the variables, not before. The simplest thing would be to do simply:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  ...
```